# How to setup search of index.ts files in vs code to see only names of folders without index.ts?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, visual-studio-code

**Now when I look for any folder by name I get a such search result:**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HUtP3.png)

**But I would prefer to see the search in this way:**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YeXQj.png)

I found only one solution to solve the problem is to name file in folder with the same name as folder but then my exports looks like this:

`export * from 'folder-name/folder-name'`

Comment: This behavior is going to be somewhat IDE dependent but `"compilerOptions": { "moduleResolution": "Node" }` allows you to inform TypeScript about the index file mapping convention.